# XFX RX 460 AMD Crimson edition driver installation help

Tags: drivers, software-installation, graphics

I have XFX RX 460 which is an AMD driver, and i'm wondering on how to install a crimson edition driver. I went to AMD website, and installed it, but after the installation the crimson edition software didn't come with it. I really need it because of overclocking and stuffs...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: FYI - http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd-rx480-od&num=1

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which has kernel 4.4

Comment: Anyone want to answer me? I have rx 460 by the way